# WHY is my installation of the beego web framework not working?

Tags: go, web-frameworks, beego

`Andres-Air:~ iivri.andre$ go get github.co/beego/bee
package github.co/beego/bee: unrecognized import path "github.co/beego/bee" (https fetch: Get https://github.co/beego/bee?go-get=1: dial tcp 199.59.243.120:443: i/o timeout`

It keeps showing me this 'error' Is anyone here familiar with the installation process?

Comment: I think you're missing an 'm': `go get github.com/beego/bee`. And according to the instructions it's `go get github.com/astaxie/beego`

Answer (score 0):

That is not the url path for Beego. You also have a typo after your `go get` command.

You need to run this from your command line:

`go get github.com/astaxie/beego`

[Installation directions from Beego](https://beego.me/docs/install/)